# Change Background color of div for sometime

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming so, I wanted to know how can I change my div container background color on click event for fraction of seconds and then revert back automatically using javascript?

```
<div data-key="65" onclick=play(this.id) id="1">
     <kbd>A</kbd>
     <span>SNARE</span>
</div>

function play(id){
    document.div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var self = this,
    old_bg = this.style.background;

this.style.background = this.style.background=='green'? 'blue':'green';
setTimeout(function(){
    self.style.background = old_bg;
}, 1000);
})


if(id==="1"){
  var audio = new Audio("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArunMichaelDsouza/javascript-30-course/master/src/01-javascript-drum-kit/sounds/snare.wav")
  audio.play();

}
```

Comment: onclick use function setTimeout; It calls function after specified time https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```js
document.getElementById("example").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var element = e.target;
  var oldColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
  var newColor = oldColor === "black" ? "green" : "black";
  
  element.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.style.backgroundColor = oldColor;
  }, 1000)
})
```

```css
#example {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" style="background-color: black;">
</div>
```